# How can I call a function that shows a "You've reached your destination" alert when the live location reaches the marked location? ReactJS and Leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, leaflet, react-leaflet

I combine two tutorials to find my location and put a marker on the map:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fkhpjp?file=index.js

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMtXhxW6t2k

How can I call a function that shows a "You've reached your destination" alert when the live location reaches the marked location?

My code:

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Map from './components/Map'

class App extends React.Component {


 render(){
   return(
     
       <div>

         <h1>test</h1>

         <Map zoom={4} center={{ lat: 39.74739, lng: -105 }} />
       </div>
     
   )
   
 }
 
}

export default App;
```

**Map.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

import LocateControl from './LocateControl';

import L from 'leaflet';
import leafGreen from '../assets/leaf-green.png';
import leafShadow from '../assets/leaf-shadow.png';


export default class MapExample extends Component {
    state = {
        greenIcon:{
        lat: 39.74739,
        lng: -105.00019,
        }
    }

    greenIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: leafGreen,
        shadowUrl: leafShadow,
        iconSize: [38, 95], // size of the icon
        shadowSize: [50, 64], // size of the shadow
        iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
        shadowAnchor: [4, 62], // the same for the shadow
        popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
        })
    render() {
    const locateOptions = {
        position: 'topright',
        strings: {
            title: 'Show me where I am, yo!'
        },
      onActivate: () => {} // callback before engine starts retrieving locations
    }

    // SHOW CURRENT LOCATION 
    const positionGreenIcon = [this.state.greenIcon.lat, this.state.greenIcon.lng]

    return (
        <Map center={this.props.center} zoom={this.props.zoom}>
        {/* MAP LAYER */}
            <TileLayer
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            />

        {/* CURRENT LOCATION */}
            <LocateControl options={locateOptions} startDirectly/>

        {/* DESTINATION LOCATION  */}
            <Marker position={positionGreenIcon} icon={this.greenIcon}>
                <Popup>
                A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                </Popup>
            </Marker>
        </Map>
    );
    }
}
```

**LocateControl.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
import Locate from "leaflet.locatecontrol";

class LocateControl extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
    const { options, startDirectly } = this.props;
    const { map } = this.props.leaflet;

    const lc = new Locate(options);
    lc.addTo(map);
    console.log("lclc: ", startDirectly)
    if (startDirectly) {
      // request location update and set location
    lc.start();
    }
    }

    render() {
    return null;
    }
}

export default withLeaflet(LocateControl);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not familiar with this.... but i know with react you can do something like `componentDidUpdate` like if blank === blank call a boolean that will show a confirmation banner.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have the two points you want to compare in two separate components.  To be able to compare them, you need to have them in the same component.  Let's add the user's current location in as part of the `Map`s state:

```js
// Map.js

    state = {
        greenIcon:{
          lat: 39.74739,
          lng: -105.00019,
        },
        userLocation: undefined,
    }
```

It starts as undefined because on component mount, we don't yet know.  We'll only know the user's location once `LocateControl` mounts, and starts running the leaflet locate control.  But we should pass a function that updates this `userLocation` state variable to the `LocateControl`, so that the `LocateControl` can set the state of the `Map` component.

```js
// Still in Map.js

updateUserLocation = userLocation => {
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    userLocation: userLocation 
  })
}

// inside your render function:
<LocateControl 
  options={locateOptions} 
  startDirectly 
  updateUserLocation={this.updateUserLocation} />
```

Now, in your `LocateControl`, you can call this function and update the state of the `Map`.  I looked into leaflet-locatecontrol and I can't seem to find exactly what method we can use to capture when the user's location is updated (`onlocationfound`?).  But you seem to have it commented out in your code for `LocateControl` in your `if (startDirectly)` statement.  We'll call our function as a prop in that statement:

```js
// LocateControl.js

...

  componentDidMount(){
    if (startDirectly) {
      // request location update and set location
      lc.start();
      const location = ?  // not sure how location is extracted from this plugin - are you?
      this.props.updateUserLocation(location)
    }
  }

...
```

So now, with every update of your leaflet-locatecontrol, your `Map` component updates the user's location in its own state.  We can act on these changes in a `componentDidUpdate` statement in the `Map` component:

```js
// Map.js again

componentDidUpdate(prevState){
  if (prevState.userLocation !== this.state.userLocation){
    // run a check here to see if the desination and user location are close together
  }
}
```

You can use [`map.distance`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-distance) to quickly calculate the distance between two points for your map.  But you need a reference to the map.

```js
// still Map.js
// root level of class declaration
mapRef = React.createRef()

// inside render:
  
  <Map ref={this.mapRef} center={...} zoom={...}></Map>
```

Inside your `componentDidUpdate`, you can now use this ref to use all the methods that the `map` gives you, including `distance`:

```js
// Map.js

componentDidUpdate(prevState){
  if (prevState.userLocation !== this.state.userLocation){
    const map = this.mapRef.current.leafletElement
    if (map.distance(this.state.userLocation, desination) < 10){
      alert("You've reached within 10 meters of your destination")
    }
  }
}
```

OK!  That's alot of steps.  For completion, here's the `Map` component with all the additions:

```js
**import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

import LocateControl from './LocateControl';

import L from 'leaflet';
import leafGreen from '../assets/leaf-green.png';
import leafShadow from '../assets/leaf-shadow.png';


export default class MapExample extends Component {

    mapRef = React.createRef()

    state = {
        greenIcon:{
          lat: 39.74739,
          lng: -105.00019,
        },
        userLocation: undefined,
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevState){
      if (prevState.userLocation !== this.state.userLocation){
        const map = this.mapRef.current.leafletElement
        if (map.distance(this.state.userLocation, desination) < 10){
          alert("You've reached within 10 meters of your destination")
        }
      }
    }

    updateUserLocation = userLocation => {
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        userLocation: userLocation 
      })
    }

    greenIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: leafGreen,
        shadowUrl: leafShadow,
        iconSize: [38, 95], // size of the icon
        shadowSize: [50, 64], // size of the shadow
        iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
        shadowAnchor: [4, 62], // the same for the shadow
        popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
        })
    render() {
    const locateOptions = {
        position: 'topright',
        strings: {
            title: 'Show me where I am, yo!'
        },
      onActivate: () => {} // callback before engine starts retrieving locations
    }

    // SHOW CURRENT LOCATION 
    const positionGreenIcon = [this.state.greenIcon.lat, this.state.greenIcon.lng]

    return (
        <Map ref={this.mapRef} center={this.props.center} zoom={this.props.zoom}>
        {/* MAP LAYER */}
            <TileLayer
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            />

        {/* CURRENT LOCATION */}
            <LocateControl options={locateOptions} startDirectly updateUserLocation={this.updateUserLocation}/>

        {/* DESTINATION LOCATION  */}
            <Marker position={positionGreenIcon} icon={this.greenIcon}>
                <Popup>
                A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                </Popup>
            </Marker>
        </Map>
    );
    }
}**
```